# Sorting One Column With Multiple Subsections In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to sort some data in google sheets that is aligned in a column, but with multiple subsections that should be sorted independently of one another.

Due to the amount of subsections I would rather not sort each one individually, so is there a better way to do it?
There is no pattern/standard to the length of the subsections though there is an accompanying section number in another column at the start of each section. The data can be reformatted however necessary to sort the subsections.
I hope the attached sample visual can help you understand my goal.

Google sheets page shown with an example of the current data and the desired result. The current data has 2 columns, one that is empty except for numbers counting up at the start of each subsection, and one with the associated data within each section. The desired results has the data in the data column sorted in ascending order within each subsection, but the data between subsections has not been sorted in any way:
[image]

I first tried using the built-in advanced sorting options in google sheets though this did not provide an option that would correctly sort the subsections.

I considered writing a custom function to perform the task but accessing numerous cells from a custom function seems tricky and the official docs did not help shed light on how that would be achieved.

I also considered a looping macro that accesses the row numbers of the section numbers to know where to sort, but unfortunately I ran into the same problem as with the custom function of being unable to easily access the data in question, though I do think this might be more likely to work?

I also think it may be useful to rearrange the data to make it easier to sort.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The Range Class has a sort method.-[Range().sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following 2 patterns? In those patterns, it supposes that the section column and the data column are "B" and "C" and the 1st header row exists. Please be careful about this.

If this was different from your actual situation, please modify the range of `const range = sheet.getRange("B2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());` to your situation.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values of column "C" are sorted by the sort method of Javascript in an array. In this case, only values are sorted without sorting the cell format. But, the process cost is lower than the pattern 2.

```js
function sample1() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("B2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const { values } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [b, c], i, a) => {
    o.temp.push(c);
    if (i > 0 && b.toString()) {
      const t = o.temp.pop();
      o.values.push(o.temp);
      o.temp = [t];
    } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
      o.values.push(o.temp);
    }
    return o;
  }, { temp: [], values: [] });
  const res = values.flatMap(e => e.sort((a, b) => a - b).map(f => [f]));
  range.offset(0, 1, res.length, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

When this script is run, column "C" is sorted by the values of column "B".

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values of column "C" are sorted by the sort method of Class Range. In this case, the cell format is also sorted.

```js
function sample2() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("B2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const { values } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [b], i, a) => {
    o.temp.push(`C${i + 2}`);
    if (i > 0 && b.toString()) {
      const t = o.temp.pop();
      o.values.push(`${o.temp[0]}:${o.temp.pop()}`);
      o.temp = [t];
    } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
      o.values.push(`${o.temp[0]}:${o.temp.pop()}`);
    }
    return o;
  }, { temp: [], values: [] });
  sheet.getRangeList(values).getRanges().forEach(r => r.sort(3));
}
```

When this script is run, column "C" is sorted by the values of column "B".

#### Note:

- When I tested those patterns using your showing situation, I confirmed that no error occurred and the correct sort was done. So, please test my scripts with your showing situation in your question. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [sort(sortSpecObj) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out albeit a heads up is that this gives the output separately:*

```js
=let(Σ,filter(row(A2:A),A2:A<>""), Λ,tocol(,1),
 reduce(Λ,A2:A,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(c="",Λ,ifna(hstack(c,sort(tocol(offset(offset(c,,2),,,xlookup(row(c)+1,Σ,Σ,rows(A:A),1)-row(c)),1)))))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who came up with answers but as it turns out I was overcomplicating things.

All I needed to do was fill in all the empty cells of the header row, then sort the rows together in the advanced range sorting options menu first by the header row then by the data row.

Thank you so much for your help!